# Executing shell script from Tcl

Tags: tcl

I'm attempting to run a shell script from TCL. I'm having a bit of trouble though as it's not working or giving me an error to troubleshoot. I'm pretty sure my issue is coming from not having "run" formatted properly. Any help is appreciated.

```
set run "sshpass -p 'password' ssh user@ip 'bash -s' <"
set sh "test.sh"
set cmd [list $run $sh $arg1 $arg2]

if {[catch {eval [linsert $cmd 0 "exec"]} status]} {
  foreach line [split $status "\n"] {
    if {[string match *text* $line]} {
       //do something
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm on another platform so I can't test this properly (especially since `arg1` and `arg2` are unknown), but try `exec $run $sh $arg1 $arg2` instead of `eval [linsert $cmd 0 "exec"]`.

Comment: Share the error message as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up removing the run variable and adding it directly. Works fine now.

```
set sh "test.sh"
set cmd [list sshpass -p 'password' ssh user@ip 'bash -s' \< $sh $arg1 $arg2]

if {[catch {eval [linsert $cmd 0 "exec"]} status]} {
  foreach line [split $status "\n"] {
    if {[string match *text* $line]} {
       //do something
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Correct. That's because unlike bash or other languages, exec in tcl operates on a list (or arguments) instead of a string. Therefore the original command was trying to execute a program named `sshpass -p 'password' ssh user@ip 'bash -s' <` instead of `sshpass`

Comment: Those single quotes… they will cause confusion. `'` is a special character to bash, but not _at all_ to Tcl (which uses `{`…`}` for the same job, except they're nestable).